# Not showing Created folder in My App directory MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

```
string mainDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory,"logs");


if (!Directory.Exists(mainDir))
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory(mainDir);
}
```

I am trying to create folder to save log txt file in my project application directory i am writing below code but its not showing any file or folder

mainDir return this below path " **/data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/files/logs**" when i see the applications directory it is having only cache directory not creating logs directory. can you help anything wrong.

Comment: i have edited my code Pls check this actually i have checked this also but i did not see "files" folder also

Comment: Did you check the directory with Android Studio's Device File Explorer?

Comment: Actually i checked in simulator project folder

Comment: It was created but hidden.  You can use the directory directly.

Comment: Yes it is saying that its created but its not visible

Comment: Yes, you can check my answer. Using the **Android Studio's Device File Explorer** can visit the directory. Did you want to use a path that can be found by the android system file manager?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have created the directory successfully. It didn't show because the directory with path `Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename)` can't be found by the Android System File Manager.

But you can find it with the **Android Studio's Device File Explorer**. In addition, you can try to check if the directory is created or not by the following code:

```
string mainDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory,"logs");
var check = Directory.Exists(mainDir);
```